Why do I get "module could not be found" when trying to connect dbt to an SQLite database?
I have a dbt profiles.yml file in "C:\Users\my_name\.dbt\profiles.yml":
euros2024:
  outputs:

    dev:
      type: sqlite
      threads: 1
      database: 'db_dev'
      schema: 'main'
      schemas_and_paths:
        main: 'C:\Users\my_name\PycharmProjects\dbt\euros2024\dev.db'
      schema_directory: '/my_project/data'
      extensions:
        - '/path/to/sqlite-digest/digest.so'

    prod:
      type: sqlite
      threads: 1
      database: <database name>
      schema: 'main'
      schemas_and_paths:
        main: '/my_project/data/etl.db'
      schema_directory: '/my_project/data'
      extensions:
        - '/path/to/sqlite-digest/digest.so'

  target: dev

Database is located at "C:\Users\my_name\PycharmProjects\dbt\euros2024\dev.db". When I run dbt debug from the euros2024 folder I get:
12:42:49  Running with dbt=1.5.11
12:42:49  dbt version: 1.5.11
12:42:49  python version: 3.12.4
12:42:49  python path: C:\Users\my_name\PycharmProjects\dbt\Scripts\python.exe
12:42:49  os info: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
12:42:49  Using profiles.yml file at C:\Users\my_name\.dbt\profiles.yml
12:42:49  Using dbt_project.yml file at C:\Users\my_name\PycharmProjects\dbt\euros2024\dbt_project.yml
12:42:49  Configuration:
12:42:49    profiles.yml file [OK found and valid]
12:42:49    dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
12:42:49  Required dependencies:
12:42:49   - git [OK found]

12:42:49  Connection:
12:42:49    database: db_dev
12:42:49    schema: main
12:42:49    schemas_and_paths: {'main': 'C:\\Users\\my_name\\PycharmProjects\\dbt\\euros2024\\dev.db'}
12:42:49    schema_directory: /my_project/data
12:42:49  Registered adapter: sqlite=1.5.0
12:42:49    Connection test: [ERROR]

12:42:49  1 check failed:
12:42:49  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Runtime Error
  Database Error
    The specified module could not be found.


Check your database credentials and try again. For more information, visit:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile

Profile named in dbt_project.yml is euros2024. I expect the dbt debug command to connect successfully to the dev.db file. I tried to specify schema_directory the same as the folder of the dev.db file and switching to forward slashes in the profiles.yml.

.dbt\ or \dbt\ ?

They exists both. \dbt\ is where i created my project, while once you initiate dbt in that project (dbt init command), it will create .dbt\ folder for its profiles.yml file
